# How do I prove that $\left\{\left.\frac{m}{2n+1}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{3(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$?

Tags: real-analysis, elementary-set-theory

My Professor told me both sets were equal and that I must use the principle of inclusion and exclusion.

Using the principle of inclusion

$$\left\{\left.\frac{3m}{3(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}\subset\left\{\left.\frac{m}{3(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$$

But I don't know how manipulate either set to apply the principle exclusion.

Comment: Assume an element exists in the l.h.s, show that you can find $m,n$ such that it is in the r.h.s

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Hint for the inclusion in the other direction: $$
3(2n+1)=6n+3=6n+2+1=2(3n+1) + 1$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not too familiar with the inclusion-exclusion principle, but I think it is used for counting the amount of elements in a set. I will thus try to help you prove the statement without this.

Let x be an element of $\left\{ \frac{3m}{3(2n+1)}\big| m,n \in \mathbb{Z} \right\}$. Then there are integers $m _x$ and $n_y$ such that $$x=\frac{3m_x}{3(2n_y+1)}.$$ Is there a $y$ in $$\left\{\frac{m}{3(2n+1)}\big|m,n \in \mathbb{Z}\right\}$$ such that $x=y$? Yes there is: If $y=m_y/3(2n_y+1)$, $n_y=n_x$ and $m_y=3m_x$, then $y=x$. Then the inclusion follows.

Answer (score 1):

Let
$A
=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{2n+1}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}
$
and
$B
=\left\{\left.\frac{m}{3(2n+1)}\right|m,n\in\mathbb{Z}\right\}$?
$.

$x \in A
\implies
x
=\frac{m}{2n+1}
=\frac{3m}{3(2n+1)}
\implies x \in B
$.

Therefore
$A \subseteq B$.

$x \in B
\implies
x
=\frac{m}{3(2n+1)}
=\frac{m}{6n+3}
=\frac{m}{2(3n+1)+1}
\implies x \in A
$.

Therefore
$B \subseteq A$.

Therefore
$A = B$.